# Office Web App not working for excel alone

Tags: excel, 2016, office-web-apps

In our SP2016 on-prem environment, we have 4 web applications.In all webapplications, Office web app is not working for excel files alone, word/ppt files open fine with OWA. UAT and Prodution share the same OWA server and this behaviour is the same in UAT and production. How to troubleshoot or fix this issue?

Below  is the error message:

We're sorry. We ran into a problem completing your request.
Please try that again in a few minutes.

Comment: To clarify, Office Web Apps is not compatible with SharePoint 2016. Did you mean you are using Office Online Server? Did you gather any ULS logs from SharePoint and OOS? The error message you provided doesn't allow us to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: We are using Office Web Apps with SP2016. Below is the log from ULS: SPFederationAuthenticationModule.IsRedirectToLogOnPage: Detected a redirection but the redirect is not to a known signin page: https://SiteURL/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={A0745038-9DA6-4BC1-BB54-D2D59B93A5FD}&file=AI%20ABW%20Action%20Items.xlsx&action=default

Answer (score 0):

Office Web Apps 2013 is unsupported with SharePoint 2016. You must deploy Office Online Server instead. Not much we can help you with here as OWA won't work due to missing the ECS features introduced into OOS (ECS was removed in SharePoint 2016 and expects those features from OOS).